# Embedding a tableau dashboard into react messes up the formatting of the dashboard

Tags: tableau-api, visualization

I have a tableau dashboard that I am trying to embed into a react website using the [tableau-api npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tableau-api). Although it looks fine on tableau public, the layout changes when I embed it. How do I ensure that the layout stays the same when I embed it in react?

Edit: here is my code. I used [this answer](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C6KGOSA3/embedding-tableau-into-a-react-app) as reference

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import tableau from 'tableau-api';
 
class Visualization extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.initTableau()
  }
 
  initTableau() {
    const vizUrl = 'url';
    const vizContainer = this.vizContainer;
    let viz = new window.tableau.Viz(vizContainer, vizUrl)
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={(div) => { this.vizContainer = div }}>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
 
export default Visualization;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options you should take a look at

1. Change the size of your dashboard from automatic to fixed (reference [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dashboards_organize_floatingandtiled.htm)). This will help if you have floating elements in your dashboard
2. Add your preferred device to the dashboard panel

[image: Dashboard panel]

3. Change the fit option to entire view

[image: Fit option]

If none of these options work, I would recommend you share a photo of your dashboard and your code to be able to debug

Comment: Option 3 worked for me, thanks! I also added my code for posterity